# Set-theoretic induction formulation from the first and second order axioms.

Tags: logic, induction, first-order-logic, second-order-logic

The usual induction used in the "traditional mathematics" (that does not care about logic and foundations as, for example, basic real analysis), reads as follows.

> **Principle of mathematical induction (PI):** If $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb N$ such that
>
> - $0\in X$
> - $n\in X\Rightarrow n+1\in X$
>
> then $X=\mathbb N$.

I'd like to understand how this "set-theoretic formulation" relates to the formal first and second order formulations.

Using [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3377308/70305) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) as reference, we have (correct me if I'm wrong):

> **First order induction schema:** it includes the axiom
> $$(\phi(0) \land\forall n(\phi(n)\to\phi(n+1)))\to \forall n\phi(n),\tag{1}$$
> for every first-order formula $\phi$.
>
> **Second order induction axiom:**
> $$\forall P((P(0)\land \forall n(P(n)\to P(n+1))\to \forall nP(n)).\tag{2}$$

*Question 1:* Take $X\subset \mathbb N$. Since $(2)$ is valid for all $P$, it is valid for the case where $P(x)$ is the sentence "$x\in X$". Thus, $(2)$ implies the PI. Is this reasoning correct?

*Question 2:* Take $X\subset \mathbb N$ that have the form $\{n\in \mathbb N\mid \psi(n) \}$, where $\psi$ is a first-order formula. Since $\psi$ is a first-order formula, $(1)$ is valid for $\phi=\psi$. Since "$\psi(x)$" is equivalent to "$x\in X$", $(1)$ implies the PI **provided that** $X$ can be defined by a first-order formula. Is this reasoning correct?

*Question 3:* Can the first order induction schema be used to obtain the PI without any restriction on $X$? If not, is the "traditional mathematics" always based on the second-order version?

*Question 4:* For the practical purposes of the "traditional mathematics", would the restriction of the PI to the cases where $X$ is definable by first order formulas be too severe? There are results that cannot be proved with this restriction?

Comment: The consistency of Peano Arithmetic (PA) cannot be proved by PA (Goedel).  To the extent that traditional mathematics is interested in PA being consistent, that's one answer to your question 3 :-)